# `boost::asio` `async_resolve` hangs on Linux, what may be a reason?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost, tcp

I write complex TCP/IP client application that generates a lot of outgoing TCP connections. I try to use `boost::asio` as portable TCP/IP networking implementation in C++.

I found following issue. See the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    io_service io;
    thread ioThread([&io]()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!io.run())
                this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
        }
    });
    ioThread.detach();
    ip::tcp::resolver r(io);
    ip::tcp::resolver::query q("www.boost.org", "80");
    atomic<bool> done(false);
    r.async_resolve(q, [&done](const boost::system::error_code& error, ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator)
    {
        if (error)
            wprintf(W("Error!\r\n"));
        else
        {
            ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;
            while (iterator != end)
            {
                ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iterator++;
                std::cout << endpoint << std::endl;
            }
        }
        done.store(true);
    });
    while (!done.load())
        this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
    return 0;
}
```

This code runs background thread to execute `io_service::run` method. It is supposed that we'll have multiple sockets that use this `io_service` to perform asyncrhonous operations.

On Windows (Visual Studio 2013 x64) this code runs well and prints endpoint address.

On CentOS Linux 6 with boost 1.60 and clang 3.4.2 it hangs.

Are there any ideas why does `async_resolve` never completes?

Comment: The code you have included does not compile, [mcve].

Comment: Code is compiled without problems, of course, if you add required header files. Tested on VS 2013 and clang 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your thread function does not reset the `boost::asio::io_service` instance. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) says:

> [`reset()`] must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions
>   when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the
>   io_service being stopped or running out of work.

In your program, the `boost::asio::io_service` instance returns because it runs out of work, so you can't call it again (i.e. on the next loop iteration) without calling `reset()` first.

There is a race condition in your program that will let it work in some cases and not work in some cases. If the resolver operations are enqueued in time for the *first* time `run()` is invoked then it will work. If not then it won't work. This should explain why it works on one OS but not another.

One more note not directly related to your problem is that your thread function calling `run()` in a loop is somewhat awkward. If you want to control the duration of `run()`, using [`io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) may be a better approach.